# Bold expression in R plot axis labels

Tags: r, axis-labels

I am trying to draw a map for which axis labels are respectively longitudes in °E and °W and latitudes in °S and °N.  No problem with that using `expression(30~degree~N)` for instance.

The thing is that I'd like to make these labels bold and when I use   `expression(bold(30~degree~N))` only "N" is bold but not "30" neither the degree symbol ("°").

The following example will show you what is my problem exactly:

```
par(mar=rep(6,4))
library(maps)
image(seq(-180,180,1),seq(-90,90,1),array(NA,c(length(seq(-180,180,1)),length(seq(-90,90,1)))),xlab="",ylab="",xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
map(add=T,interior=F,lwd=3)

axis(1,at=seq(-200,200),rep(NA,401),lwd.ticks=0,lwd=5)
axis(3,at=seq(-200,200),rep(NA,401),lwd.ticks=0,lwd=5)
axis(2,at=seq(-100,100),rep(NA,201),lwd.ticks=0,lwd=5)
axis(4,at=seq(-100,100),rep(NA,201),lwd.ticks=0,lwd=5)
par(font=2)
axis(1,at=seq(-150,150,30),c(expression(bold(150~degree~W)),expression(120~degree~W),
                         expression(90~degree~W),expression(60~degree~W),
                         expression(30~degree~W),expression(0~degree),
                         expression(30~degree~E),expression(60~degree~E),
                         expression(90~degree~E),expression(120~degree~E),
                         expression(150~degree~E)),lwd.ticks = 5,cex.axis=1.1,font.axis=2,tck=.022,las=2)
```

As an example, I just used `bold` for 150°W and as you can see I only have the "W" in bold:
[image]

You can notice that I've also tried `par(font=2)` and `font.axis=2` but both did not fix my problem.

Comment: What package is `map()` in? It doesn't seem to be a base function.

Comment: Oh sorry. Changed it in the script above. The package is `maps`.